# CouchDB IP Address and Port

Tags: ip, couchdb, port, vagrant

When I start couchDB I have it running on `http://127.0.0.1:5984/`. I have another program I need to run on the same port, so I want to change the couchDB one to something else. Any ideas?

Comment: With a quick Google search you can find [material](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.4.x/configuring.html#virtual-hosts) about CouchDB config files and Virtual Hosts, which allow to specify your desired port.

Comment: So I'll need to run a virtual host? @mathielo

Answer (score 6):

Specify the port in your `local.ini` config:

```
[httpd]
port = 5984
```

Comment: I changed it to `5983` but it still opens in `5984`

Comment: Did you restart Couch? You can even just try to restart the VM using vagrant. Also, is your config file in the same directory as `default.ini`?